# Move gameObject in its facing direction

Tags: unity, rotation, vector, transformation

I have the following four gameObjects, they have, respectively, the rotations: -90, 0, 90, 180. I want them to move as denoted in the image below

[image]

---

This is what I got so far:

```
public class Projecttile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(transform.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

The result of my code is the following: [image]

**Why does my code result in this outcome, and how can I make each gameObject move in the direction it's facing?**

Comment: **Note:** Each projecttile only got the Projecttile script attached to it, there is nothing else interfering with it.

Comment: Did you [read the docs on transform.Translate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) to verify what coordinate space it uses when you don't provide a `Space` parameter? Or did you mean to type `Vector3.up` instead of `transform.up`?